# Java servlets HttpSession

Tags: jsp, session, jakarta-ee, web-applications, servlets

if I call request.getSession() does it return me the whole session in the web server? or does it return only the session that is associated with the current user?

Comment: What would the "whole session" be? A session is user (or to be more precise, session ID) specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

request.getSession() only returns the session that is associated with current user.

**You can check this in your web application for accessing same object that are stored in session for different browser, such as firefox or IE which keeps each own session.**

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession%28%29
said

> Returns the current session associated with this request, or if the
>   request does not have a session, creates one.

Answer (score 0):

According to JAVA API Documentation, it returns the current session associated with this request, or if the request does not have a session, creates one.

So its for current user.